# What is the static exchange approximation?

Tags: atomic-physics, terminology, physical-chemistry, approximations

In this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.20.1474), on the 4th page (and throughout), they talk about studying electron-helium scattering in the "static-exchange approximation". I have scoured the literature and have not been able to figure out what this. There this [power point](http://people.physics.anu.edu.au/~jps107/docs/scattering6.pdf) which gives some really brief description but outside of that I can't figure out what it is. Apparently it is sometimes called the "continuum Hartree-Fock approximation". It seems like it gives a model of the potential that accounts for exchange effects in electron-atomic (or molecular) scattering. Can anyone give a self-contained explanation for this approximation?

Comment: [Does this help](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=i5IPWXDQlcIC&pg=PA682&lpg=PA682&dq=scattering+static-exchange+approximation&source=bl&ots=F15o38Evu7&sig=ACfU3U2kl4NadXZBqCDDOZpxvHm40LtxTQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNyandqevjAhXhuXEKHdPiCmoQ6AEwCnoECGMQAQ#v=onepage&q=static-exchange%20approximation&f=false)?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.